# vb.net - set form background color programatically from a string variable

Tags: vb.net, formatting, backcolor

I've got a string that contains an RGB value, so like "224,224,224".
I'm trying to use that value to set the background color of a form, but its erroring out and I'm not sure why.

I'm trying...

```
 If Not this_dialog_backcolor = "" Then _
     new_dialog.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(this_dialog_backcolor)
```

I get the exception

> control does not support transparent background colors.

I tried amending the string to contain a 4th value, so it became "255,224,224,224" and this also errored, giving the exception that the arithmatic operation resulted in an overload.

I also tried having the string formatted like so:

```
 Color [A=255, R=33, G=33, B=33]
```

This time i get the exception 'Conversion from string 'Color [A=255, R=33, G=33, B=33]' to type integer is not valid.

Any help appriciated.

Comment: Is this related to a WPF application or is this a WinForms one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[FromArgb](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.color.fromargb?view=netframework-4.8) is a method that doesn't accept a string as parameter. So an automatic conversion happens here and you cannot be sure that this conversion do what you need to do.
If you had [Option Strict On](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-strict-statement) this error would have been catched at compile time.

You can approach your problem in a different way, for example, you could split the string in its subparts and then call the FromArgb using the proper color values

```
Dim s As String = "224,224,224"

if Not string.IsNullOrEmpty(s) Then
    Dim p = s.Split(","c).Select(Function(x) int32.Parse(x.Trim()))
    form1.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(p(0),p(1),p(2))
End If
```

Comment: I like that - its tidier than what i came up with. Just implementing now...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ColorConverter` from the namespace `System.Drawing`.

```
Dim converter = New ColorConverter()
Dim color = DirectCast(converter.ConvertFromString("255,224,224"), Color)
```

It can also convert colors given as web color name like `"PaleVioletRed"` and in hex format like `"#FF0D60"`.

Comment: Maybe a note that, since the OP is referring to a Form, to support transparent colors it's only required to `SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);` in the consructor.

Answer (score 0):

So I've managed to achieve what i was after, but I'm not sure on its efficiency... it feels a bit dirty...

```
 If custom_color_scheme = true Then
 Dim back_color_bits() As String = this_dialog_backcolor.Replace(" ", "").Split(",")
 If Not this_dialog_backcolor = "" Then
     new_dialog.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(Convert.ToInt32(back_color_bits(0)), _
         Convert.ToInt32(back_color_bits(1)), Convert.ToInt32(back_color_bits(2)))
 End If
```

Like i said, it works, but i'm sure there must be a cleaner way. 
anybody?